# How to share Websecurity with virtual directory in Webmatrix

Tags: directory, virtual, webmatrix

I've created the StarterSite from Webmatrix and added an Admin role for Websecurity. I have a separate application (tinyfilemanager.net) setup in a virtual directory as per the website's instructions and I need help to integrate the same Websecurity and roles to this application, so that only Admins can access the app.

When logged in to the StarterSite WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated = true however it is always false for the tinyfilemanager app setup in the virtual directory. How can I share the Websecurity object with the tinyfilemanager application?

Comment: I'm also trying to do something similar to this but no luck so far.